# Ошибка в конвертации строки в дату

Tags: python, datetime

пытаюсь конвертировать строку в дату, вылетает ошибка

```
time data '79:16:03' does not match format '%d:%H:%M'
```

Мой код:

```
from datetime import datetime
str_to_conv = '79:16:03'
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(str_to_conv, '%d:%H:%M')
```

Comment: А что это за дата?

Comment: как минимум str_to_conv у вас не строка..

Comment: меня терзают смутные сомнения - вопрос вообще о земном календаре? :-D

Comment: учитывая 79 суток в месяце нет... и это и есть та самая ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас несуществующая дата. Где вы видели 79-й день ? В месяце их ведь либо 28, либо 30, либо 31.